# Access data in Adapter From Activity

Tags: android-activity, adapter

i want to access data inside Adapter from Activity, and then i will passing the data from activity to call API.. here is my data inside PremiumAdapter.java :

```
public class PremiumVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
static List<PremiumVideo> data;

public PremiumVideoAdapter(List<PremiumVideo> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PremiumVideo video = data.get(position);
    final VH vh = (VH) holder;
    String harga = video.price;  //Target Data
    String content_id = video.content_id;  // Target Data
```

and i want to access from here PreviewActivity.java :

```
 btnBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            // Access data in Adapter from here


            Call<APIResponse<DataJsonCharging>> call = ServicesFactory.getService().getCharging(/* Passing data from adapter here*/);
```